# Ant Design Upload show file size with file name

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, upload, antd

How to display file size with name in antd upload in React.js ?
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tyyv.png)
is it possible to show the file size without custom code and styling?

if it is not possible so i can show the file Size with custom code but i need to display the file size with antd props or something else

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, Upload } from 'antd';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function UploadFile() {
    const [fileList, setFileList] = useState([
        {
            uid: '-1',
            name: 'xxx.png',
            status: 'done',
            url: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        },
    ]);

    const props = {
        action: 'https://reactnative.dev/img/tiny_logo.png',
        multiple: true,
    };
    // SAVE FILE IN LOCAL STORAGE
    const onChange = ({ fileList: newFileList }) => {
        setFileList(newFileList);
        localStorage.setItem('image', JSON.stringify(fileList));
    }

    return (
        <Upload
            listType="picture"
            beforeUpload={(fileList) => {
                console.log('FILE', fileList.size);
                return true;
            }
            }
        >
            <Button icon={
                <UploadOutlined />}>Upload</Button >
        </Upload>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think AntD supports showing file size on the upload list.

In your case, you can capture the file size using [onChange](https://ant.design/components/upload#onchange) function, which receives not only `fileList` but also the file object containing the file size in bytes. You can save the file size to state and manually render using the itemRender ([example](https://ant.design/components/upload#components-upload-demo-drag-sorting)) prop.